# How to use Azure Key Vault in SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: azure-keyvault

I would like to retrieve the password I saved in AKV and use it on my stored procedure. Is this possible?

Comment: For an on-premise SQL Server, or for SQL Server on Azure?

Comment: SQL server on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system-assigned managed identity for your Azure SQL server to access secrets in your Azure Key Vault

Enable System-Assigned managed identity for your Azure SQL server

Add access policy in your Azure Key vault for the Azure SQL server managed identity with GET permissions on secrets

Now, you can use System-Assigned identity on your Azure SQL server to retrieve Azure Key Vault secrets

To use managed identities to connect to your Azure SQL Database, you need to enable Azure Active Directory (AD) authentication and create the managed users in the database

**Reference**: [How to Use Managed Identities with Azure SQL Database | Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-managed-identity-with-azure-sql-database)

Comment: The guide shows how to connect .net apps to SQL database. But what if I just need to call the secrets from AKV to my sql stored procs.